# Install and Enable Tomcat 7 on Plesk 11.5

Tags: tomcat, plesk, centos6

I have a CentOS 6.4 64-bit running Plesk v11.5 and would like to install / enable Tomcat 7.

My first attempt was via the Plesk *add components* and tomcat **6** was installed successfully.  Since I need tomcat **7**, this was not an option so I removed version 6 from the server.

My next attempt is to install tomcat 7 directly but before I do so, I would like to ask a few questions:

1. I can understand this will not be embedded in Plesk so changing config files etc.. will need to be done manually which is ok - but will this interfere with Plesk's operations?
2. Can I somehow embed it in Plesk and/ or upgrade tomcat 6 instead of install version 7?
3. Do I still need to upgrade the Plesk license to [Power Pack](http://kb.parallels.com/119012) if I install it directly on the server?
4. Anything else I should be aware of please? Ports? Paths?

Answer (score 0):

My Plesk is actually running on 10.4.4.57 and I installed a tomcat7 an the server just before I noticed, thas Plesk has an embedded solution.

1. So far there are no problems. Tomcat ist reachable through every Domain registered in Plesk.
2. Have´n t find asolution for this, sorry.
3. As far as I understand this is only necessary if you want to manage Tomcat from within the Plesk Panel
4. I installed my Tomcat in /usr/share/tomcat7 (Plesk´s Tomcat installation is in /usr/share/tomcat6) and had no sideeffects.